# Querying EventLogs over WMI and the nature of DCOM

Tags: java, wmi, dcom, event-log

First some background:

I'm currently using j-interop to query WMI calls to a Windows box from a Linux box, I'm running this query against WMI:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent'
```

And executing it as a notification query so I can get the data back as soon as it's created. However this proves an issue at (rare) times.

Say, when a user changes permissions on a root folder, I can be flooded with thousands of logs, the system can handle this fine, java and the interop code is happy, however the WMI cycle seems to be this:

```
Hook into event
while(forever)
{
    Query server for next event.
    Do work with event.
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work for me, being as I'll jump back and forth from the server thousands of times, program doesn't choke but it sure takes *forever*, I can't find a way to get the event to return all pending events (I think).

The next choice is to keep track of the last record ID returned by WMI, and do a straight up query for all events where their record ID is greater than the last, I'm *assuming* this will work better, however I'm not familiar with DCOM.

**So my question:**

If I run a ExecQuery instead of a notification query, will I have to dance back and forth between client/server to iterate through each record returned by the query due to the nature of Distributed COM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main solution here is to not use DCOM for this, it's terribly inefficient and I've put servers under a decent amount of CPU strain executing large sets of DCOM instructions.

I'm looking into Windows RPC Java implementations if I wanted to do this remotely, or WinAPI locally.